# any way to post wordpress post from out side

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Is it possible that I can publish a post on my WordPress site without logging in to admin panel. I want a form where I can write post title, post body, author id, and publish button. I want to use MySQL database connection, so I don't need to login every time to post. This form will be on my local host and connected with my WordPress database. When I fill this form, it should add the post in database and publish on my site.

Comment: You could use the mail functionality to do this. Have a look here: http://www.wpbeginner.com/beginners-guide/how-to-add-posts-by-email-in-wordpress/ - if you want to take it a step further, you could create a php mailer form that will send the mail to your blog, thusly creating the solution you asked for.

Answer (score 2):

There is WP REST API and JSON API are available.
Please use this plugins to you can post post from outside of word press.

Comment: can you please explain ... help me if any code post here . im new to this thanks

Comment: thanks , but i need php code on my local server so i used to post on my site

Comment: PHP  HTML V1 <?php

$request = new HttpRequest();
$request->setUrl('http://localhost/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/');
$request->setMethod(HTTP_METH_POST);

$request->setHeaders(array(
  'postman-token' => 'dd719f14-dca5-9d25-f502-4cc7c4cf551d',
  'cache-control' => 'no-cache'
));

$request->setBody('[{
      "Id": "",
      "date" : "11-May-2016",
      "title" : "Post from API",
      "content" : "My first post",
      "excerpt" : ""
      
}]');

try {
  $response = $request->send();

  echo $response->getBody();
} catch (HttpException $ex) {
  echo $ex;
}

Comment: <php yourdatabasename:dataname ;, username: root;,password:password;, like this something php with html .. i can post from my local server to my wordpress blog database without any wordpress link imean plugin or api ... script connect with database and posts show from database on my blog

Comment: If live server in database directly not accessible another server then you getting problem in connectivity of database.

Answer (score 0):

You can use is below plugin for create post from front side.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/frontier-post/

Comment: is it possible without any plugin

Comment: You can create with code. See : http://voodoopress.com/how-to-post-from-your-front-end-with-no-plugin/
Or better you can call WP Rest API

Comment: <php yourdatabasename:dataname ;, username: root;,password:password;, like this something php with html .. i can post from my local server to my wordpress blog database without any wordpress link imean plugin or api ... script connect with database and posts show from database on my blog

Answer (score 0):

Find PHP Code for calling Json API

```
PHP HTML V2 

<?php
$client = new http\Client;
$request = new http\Client\Request;
$body = new http\Message\Body;
$body->append('[{
      "Id": "",
      "date" : "11-May-2016",
      "title" : "Post from API",
      "content" : "My first post",
      "excerpt" : ""
      }]');
$request->setRequestUrl('http://localhost/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/');
$request->setRequestMethod('POST');
$request->setBody($body);
$request->setHeaders(array(
  'postman-token' => 'a2a42c5a-002f-fc4e-15ea-4d734761f608',
  'cache-control' => 'no-cache'
));
$client->enqueue($request)->send();
$response = $client->getResponse();
echo $response->getBody();
```

PHP HTML V1

```
<?php

$request = new HttpRequest();
$request->setUrl('http://localhost/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/');
$request->setMethod(HTTP_METH_POST);

$request->setHeaders(array(
  'postman-token' => 'f421932b-cc55-5306-8fb3-5ca7bba3dd1d',
  'cache-control' => 'no-cache'
));

$request->setBody('[{
      "Id": "",
      "date" : "11-May-2016",
      "title" : "Post from API",
      "content" : "My first post",
      "excerpt" : ""

}]');

try {
  $response = $request->send();

  echo $response->getBody();
} catch (HttpException $ex) {
  echo $ex;
}
```

Comment: <php  yourdatabasename:dataname ;, username: root;,password:password;,    like this something php with html do i can post from my local server to my wordpress blog database without any wordpress link imean plugin or api ... script connect with database and posts show from database on my blog ...